# Entity Framework can not be found after merging with ILMerge

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ilmerge

Hope you can help me, for I ran out of ideas. I use Entity Framework 6 in my project that is good tested and worked just perfectly.

Until I decided to merge everythig into one `.exe` file. Since then, I've got problems. For this task I decided to use `ILMerge`. Installed it as a nuget package and wrote a `Ilmerge.CSharp.targets` like this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
   <Target Name="AfterBuild">
      <CreateItem Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.dll'">
         <Output ItemName="AssembliesToMerge" TaskParameter="Include" />
      </CreateItem>
      <PropertyGroup>
         <ReferenceAssemblies>C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5</ReferenceAssemblies>
      </PropertyGroup>     
      <Exec Command="&quot;..\packages\ilmerge.2.14.1208\tools\Ilmerge.exe&quot; /out:@(MainAssembly) &quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(AssembliesToMerge->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')"/>
      <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
   </Target>               
</Project>
```

After a successful compilation I run my solution and get a runtime error

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

Any ideas? By the way... Log4Net seems also not working after merging.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: So you have one executable left in your solution. Have your tried configuring the NuGet packages for this project? (Project -> Context Menu -> "Manage NuGet Packages"). Here you should ensure that the Entity framework, Log4Net and other packages are installed for the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration file (app.config) you most likely have something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>    
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
         <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <!-- more stuff here -->
</configuration>
```

Note that there are multiple lines there which reference types in EntityFramework assembly, for example:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

But after you merged everything into one assembly - no EntityFramework dll can be found any more. You have to fix those references to point to *your main assembly* instead. Suppose your application .exe is named MergeTest.exe. Then to fix the issue, replace every occurence of EntityFramework reference to MergeTest:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, MergeTest" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, MergeTest">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, MergeTest" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <!-- More stuff here -->
</configuration>
```

Same story with log4net references.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But now I get an error: `An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Could not load file or assembly 'MyMerge, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)` What can it be?

Comment: You have to delete whole reference ("EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" replace with just "MyMerge"), so remove public key token, version and culture too.

Comment: @Julia also if your main assembly (MyMerge) has strong name (so is signed with snk key) - you have to replace EntityFramework reference with valid strong reference to your assembly (MyMerge, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<your_public_key_token_here>).

Comment: @Evk So I've replaced EntityFramework with the name of my executable inside my .config file, but now I get this error: 
System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array. 
I haven't had this error before.
Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @mateuszlewko hard to say without more details. Where this exception is thrown, what is stack trace and so on. This exception is very generic and can be thrown in many many cases.

Comment: @mateuszlewko you can post a new question with details (I suppose they will not fit in a comment) or open a chat and we'll see what is the problem.